# Delete ontology individuals with OWL API not deleted in Protege

Tags: eclipse, protege, owl-api

I have an onology created in Protege. I loaded the ontology using Eclipse. I tried to delete a specific individual from ontology using the following code:

```
File file = new File("D:/diana/e/2012_2013/d/protege/picture8.owl");
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLOntology localPicture = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new StructuralReasonerFactory();
OWLReasoner reasoner = reasonerFactory.createReasoner(localPicture, config);
OWLDataFactory fac = manager.getOWLDataFactory();

//the individual that I want to delete
OWLNamedIndividual ind = fac.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create("http://www.semanticweb.org/diana/ontologies/2013/0/picture4.owl#Water1"));
OWLEntityRemover remover = new OWLEntityRemover(Collections.singleton(localPicture));
remover.visit(ind);
// or ind.accept(remover);
manager.applyChanges(remover.getChanges());
```

It seems that the individual was deleted, but when I open the ontology with Protege the individual is still there.

Could you tell me how can I delete the individual from Eclipse so as not to appear in Protege?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you saved the ontology afterwards?

You need to call `manager.saveOntology(localPicture);` after applying the changes or they are only effective for the in memory copy of the ontology.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I am new working with OWL and I taught myself watching documentation, so I have tried manager.saveOntology(localPicture, new StreamDocumentTarget(
                new ByteArrayOutputStream())); without knowing the meaning of the parameters and it did not work. Your suggestion works. Thank you.